# load_class Function

Tags: php, class, methods, autoload

I'm trying to create  a function that will autoload classes, so I can do something like this:

```
load_class('Db');
$db->query();
```

Here's my code so far. It loads the file and instantiates the class successfully, but when I try to call a method like above, I get `Call to member function` error.

Here's my code:

```
function load_class($class) {
    $file = 'classes/' . $class . '.php';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include_once($file);

        if (class_exists($class)) {
            $class = new $class();
            return $class;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the benefit of doing it like that. What is wrong with using the `new`? or if u hate `new` create a base class with a static method `create` and make all other classes inherit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`load_class` return the instance of `Db` class, if it found the declaration.

You may need to do:

```
$db = load_class('Db');
if (!$db) {
  throw new Exception('Failed to load db!');
}
$db->query();
```

But, If you want to autoload the class when you do `$db = new Db;`, then you should take a look at the ***[php's autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)***.

Example:

```
function load_class($class) {
    $file = 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include_once($file);
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('load_class');
```

Comment: this exception/error handling needs to happen inside the autoloading function, right?

Answer (score 0):

For your code to work, do it like that:

```
$db = load_class('Db');
$db->query();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I were to do that, I'd simply use `$db = new Db` — I'm trying to create a function that will do it dynamically, like CodeIgniter for example.

Comment: "magical" stuff like that is sooooo wrong. `load_class('Db')` is 16 chars. `$db = new Db` is 10-12 chars, so u don't even write less...